# parallel program in python using Threads

Tags: python

Generating the sum from adding integer numbers successively up to n where n =  2000   given by the following formula: n(n+1)/2
so far i have don it in serial.I need help on how to make it compute in parallel such that it adaptively make use of all the available processors/cores on the host computer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
n=1
v=0
start_time = datetime.now() 
while n<=10:

 (n*(n+1)/2)
 b=(n*(n+1)/2)
 n = n+1

end_time =datetime.now()

print (b)

 print('Time taken : {}'. format(end_time-start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use `multiprocessing`, which lets you create processes and assign procedures to them. Here's a code snippet that does part of what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import datetime

MAX_NUM = 10000000
NUMPROCS = 1

# LINEAR VERSION
start_time = datetime.now() 
my_sum = 0
counter = 1
while counter <= MAX_NUM:
    my_sum += counter
    counter += 1
end_time =datetime.now()

print (my_sum)
print('Time taken : {}'. format(end_time-start_time))

# THREADING VERSION
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

start_time = datetime.now() 

def sum_range(start,stop,out_q):
    i = start
    counter = 0
    while i < stop:
        counter += i
        i += 1
    out_q.put(counter)

mysums = Queue()
mybounds = [1+i for i in range(0,MAX_NUM+1,int(MAX_NUM/NUMPROCS))]
myprocs = []

for i in range(NUMPROCS):
    p = Process(target=sum_range, args=(mybounds[i],mybounds[i+1],mysums))
    p.start()
    myprocs.append(p)

mytotal = 0
for i in range(NUMPROCS):
    mytotal += mysums.get()

for i in range(NUMPROCS):
    myprocs[i].join()

print(mytotal)
end_time =datetime.now()
print('Time taken : {}'. format(end_time-start_time))
```

Although the code doesn't adaptively use processors, it does divide the task into a prespecified number of processes.

Comment: This is the error i get when i Run it

RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.